# Can metadata be added to MongoDB operations for logging purposes?

Tags: php, database, mongodb, logging, events

I have a web application written in PHP split among multiple services, which (unfortunately) all use the same Mongo database, there is no one-database-per-service or separated collections per service. Any service is able to modify any record in the database.

Given this situation, understanding production bugs becomes a very tricky process. Some records change and there is no quick way to find a history of who, when and why the record was changed. There is the possibility to follow the logs in the codebase, but this is much easier said than done.

To solve this problem, I was thinking to use [MongoDB Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) as a way of monitoring the history of changes, so I was looking for a way to incorporate some metadata in the calls to the driver so it will be present in the Change Stream, for example the service which ran the `.update()`. Does anyone know if this is possible?

If it is not, a workaround I was thinking of is to a have a "debugging" field in each record which will store the metadata, so it will appear in the change stream, but I'm feeling that this could have a high impact on performance and storage. Another alternative could be not to use the change streams at all and find another way to log the calls to the MongoDB driver in a centralized way.

I want to know if what I want to do is possible, if not if there are any alternatives and if my overall approach has any pitfalls and downsides that I don't see.

Thanks!